# Running Docker's automated repository tests with pytest

Tags: bash, automated-tests, docker-compose, pytest

I currently have a group of Docker services which I run with `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`. Once this is done, I have a test directory in which I can run `pytest` to check that all tests pass.

I would like to automate this two-step testing processing into a single one, and was looking into Docker's [automated repository tests](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/automated-testing/). In the example shown, however, the testing script `run_tests.sh` is a bash script; the tests pass if it returns 0 and fail otherwise.

How might I adapt this to make the tests pass if all [pytest](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/) tests pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that as the `command` in the `sut` service, I can simply do `pytest` instead of `run_tests.sh` as in the example.

From the [Pytest main() source code](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/_modules/_pytest/main.html) I understand that the `pytest` command returns `0` if the tests pass and `1` if they failed, which I verified by running passing/failing tests and checking the exit code using `echo $?`.